# How to properly notify caller on failure of the asynchronous operation?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Class `FeatureManager` manages some feature and looks something like this:

```
public class FeatureManager
{
    public event EventHandler FeatureEnabledChangedEvent;
    private void OnFeatureEnabledChanged()
    {
        if (FeatureEnabledChangedEvent != null)
        {
            FeatureEnabledChangedEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler FeatureEnableBusyChangedEvent;
    private void OnFeatureEnableBusyChanged()
    {
        if (FeatureEnableBusyChangedEvent != null)
        {
            FeatureEnableBusyChangedEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler FeatureEnableFailedEvent;
    private void OnFeatureEnableFailed(FeatureEnableFailedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (FeatureEnableFailedEvent!= null)
        {
            FeatureEnableFailedEvent(this, args);
        }
    }

    private bool _isFeatureEnabled 
    public bool IsFeatureEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            return _isFeatureEnabled;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (_isFeatureEnabled != value)
            {
                _isFeatureEnabled = value;
                OnFeatureEnabledChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _isFeatureEnableBusy; 
    public bool IsFeatureEnableBusy
    {
        get
        {
            return _isFeatureEnableBusy;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (_isFeatureEnableBusy != value)
            {
                _isFeatureEnableBusy = value;
                OnFeatureEnableBusyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task EnableFeature()
    {
        IsFeatureEnableBusy = true;

        try
        {             
            // By its nature, process of enabling this feature is asynchronous. 
            await EnableFeatureImpl(); // can throw exception
            IsFeatureEnabled = true; 
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            OnFeatureEnableFailed(new FeatureEnableFailedEventArgs(exc.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            IsFeatureEnableBusy = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

UI class `FeatureView` has to be notified when:

- `IsFeatureEnableBusy` changes (or, in other words when `EnableFeature` is being executed - in order to disable some controls)
- `IsFeatureEnabled` changes
- `EnableFeature` fails (when it throws exception in which case `FeatureView` displays error message
  to the user)

`EnableFeature` can be called from some Engine class `E` (automatically, during the initialization on the application's launch) and also from `FeatureView` (when user presses 'Enable' button).

In order to satisfy requirement where `FeatureView` has to be notified when `EnableFeature` fails after it's been called by `E`, I added an event `FeatureEnableFailedEvent`.

When `E` calls `EnableFeature` and `EnableFeature` throws an exception, `FeatureView` receives `FeatureEnableFailedEvent` and displays error message. But when `FeatureView` itself calls `EnableFeature` and `EnableFeature` fails, `FeatureView` catches thrown exception but also gets notified on this failure from `FeatureEnableFailedEvent` so error handler is called twice. **How to avoid this?**

One solution is to declare `EnableFeature` as an *old-style* async method (and use *BackgroundWorker*) as in the following snippet:

```
public class FeatureManager
{
    public void EnableFeatureAsync()
    {
        var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

        bgw.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {   
            IsFeatureEnableBusy = true;  
            EnableFeatureImpl(); // can throw exception
        };

        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            IsFeatureEnableBusy = false;  

            if (args.Error == null)
            {
                IsFeatureEnabled = true; 
            }
            else
            {
                OnFeatureEnableFailed(new FeatureEnableFailedEventArgs(args.Error.Message));
            }
        };

        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    } 
}
```

In this case, caller of `EnableFeatureAsync` can assume that this method runs asynchronously (suffix *Async* in method's name should be a hint) and that it has to subscribe to `FeatureEnableFailedEvent` if want to be notified on the method failure. This way `FeatureView` gets notified on `EnableFeatureAsync` failure only once so error handler is called once as it should be.

**Is this a good approach? Could this be achieved by still using async/await in some way? Is it good assuming that suffix *Async* in method's name is a good enough hint to callers so they know that this method runs as asynchronous one and that they have to look for some events to subscribe to?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review (should be on codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @BojanKomazec: Why not just allow the exception to propagate out of the `async` method and use `try`/`catch` instead of an event?

Comment: @PeterDuniho If community agrees on this, I'd be happy to move my question to appropriate forum.

Comment: @StephenCleary `FeatureView` can't catch exception thrown when some other class (`E`) calls `EnableFeature` (`FeatureView` is not a direct caller so can't use try/catch).

Comment: I don't understand, `EnableFeature()` catches the exception and doesn't rethrow it, so `FeatureView` won't catch it.

Comment: My question is more about convention rather than particular implementation. If client sees method `Foo()` declared as `async`, they expect that it can throw exception and so they might not subscribe themselves to the event `FooFailedEvent`. If that method swallows exception (and fires event), client will not be notified on the failure. Is there any convention that would tell user/client "Don't catch exception of `async` method `Foo()` in a `catch` block but subscribe to the event `FooFailedEvent` instead?

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @svick, I also don't see why your `FeatureView` catches the exception and also gets the event, when the exception is not rethrown in the handler of `FeatureManager`. But here is an different approach, which I'd prefer over yours based on events:

Use [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to let the view know when the enablement of a feature did throw an exception even when `FeatureView` is not the caller of `EnableFeature()` (btw, by convention the method should also be named EnableFeatureAsync in the first example).

```
public class FeatureManager
{
    public TaskCompletionSource<bool> FeatureCompleted { get; private set; }

    // if you still need this property
    public bool IsFeatureEnabled 
    {
        get { return FeatureCompleted.Task.IsCompleted; }
    }

    public FeatureManager() {}

    public async Task EnableFeature()
    {
        IsFeatureEnableBusy = true;

        try
        {             
            // By its nature, process of enabling this feature is asynchronous. 
            await EnableFeatureImpl(); // can throw exception
            this.FeatureCompleted.TrySetResult(true);
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            this.FeatureCompleted.TrySetException(exc);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsFeatureEnableBusy = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Your `FeatureView` instance now needs to await the Task of the TaskCompletionSource. The code could look like this:

```
public class FeatureView
{   
    // if you still need this property
    public async void HandleFeatureCompleted(FeatureManager fm) 
    {
        try
        {
            await fm.FeatureCompleted.Task;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

You have to provide the correct `FeatureManager` instance to your view. I'm not sure if this approach is appropriate if you have hundredths or even thousands of `FeatureManager` instances messages. I'd be happy if more somebody of the commenters could provide feedback about this.